# Tournament table

Tags: php, html-table

I am trying to create a tournament table using PHP.
[This is the HTML code sample.](http://jsfiddle.net/ktfkoqqc/)

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>final</th>
            <th>winner</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">team1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team2</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">team4</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team3</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">team4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team4</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">team4 vinner</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team5</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">team6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team6</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">team8</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team7</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="team">team8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="team">team8</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried creating that table using `for` loops, but that didn't work very well.
Maybe you can give some hints? I am out of ideas.

Comment: You want table to look like this? or your result table is like this and you want table to look normal ?

Comment: I want to table look like this, how is in the jsfiddle.

Comment: do you have an array from wich you generate victorious team?

Comment: Fixing grammar and markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elimination system you are working with is called "single elimination" (sometimes "head to head") and the output you wish to achieve is often called "brackets".

Have a look at:
[Generate a single elimination tournament](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22859730/1168156)
and:  [PHP Single Elimination Tournament Table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10940047/1168156)

This one can be helpful too: [Tournament bracket placement algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8355264/1168156)

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly, what i am looking for. :)